# Always got Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value inside of CallDirectoryHandler

Tags: swift, core-data, callkit

I added target `Call Directory Extension` to app, made a group, put main app and extension there, share `appname.xcdatamodeld` with main app and extension and create `CoreDataHandler` class to access CoreData with group and `appname.sqlite`

Then I made interface in main app to add phone numbers and save them in `Int64` format. It works fine - numbers saved. And I can get them inside main app like:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "NumberList")

do {
    let entries = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for item in entries {
        print(item.value(forKeyPath: "number") as! Int64)
    }
}
catch {}
```

All works, numbers printed... BUT inside `CallDirectoryHandler` with absolutely same situation I always got `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, when Call Directory Extension reloads.

What am I do wrong? And actually it all works fine BEFORE update to last Xcode and IOS version (13.4)

```
private func addOrRemoveIncrementalBlockingPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext, since date: Date) {
    print(numbers.count)                                      //<-- It shows numbers count properly!
    for entity in self.numbers {
        print(entity)                                         //<-- It shows entity! 
        let number: Int64? = entity.value(forKeyPath: "number") as? Int64
        print(entity.value(forKey: "number")!)               //<-- But fall here with nil, but attribute exists in main app!
        let isHidden: Bool? = (entity.value(forKeyPath: "is_hidden") as? Bool)!

        if isHidden != nil { context.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: number!) } else { context.removeBlockingEntry(withPhoneNumber: number!) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nowadays never use KVC (`value(forKey:)` and not even `value(forKeyPath:)` if there is actually no key **path**) to get Core Data attributes, use dot notation (`entity.number`). And do not annotate types the compiler can infer.

Comment: @vadian thank you for good pattern - it takes half day to understand, how it works, but I included it to the project completely. Sadly, it doesn't solve the problem: even with dot notation I got 0 for `entity.number` (and other entities and attributes) inside `CallDirectoryHandler`, but got normal attribute value inside main app...:( Really don't know, what 2 do...